# Linux: Shared and mounted directories

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, symbolic-link, shared-folders

Fairly-new to Linux and am trying to see if I can start getting a little clever. I have a server that contains files that I'd like to have "locally" accessible on other servers  directly under the `/` directory:

```
Server1
    /opt/
        fizz/
            buzz/ --> the directory that contains interesting stuff

Server2
    /opt/
    /buzz/ --> references the Server1/opt/fizz/buzz/ directory
```

I spent some time reading up on this and I stumbled across all sorts of terms like "shared directories", "mounted drives", "mounted directories", etc.

What is the best solution for what I need?  Essentially, the contents in this `buzz/` directory are huge and would be very expensive to query `Server1` for every time I want them on another server. It would be nice if each server had a local link to that directory as if the directory was stored locally, right there on the server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

> [it] would be very expensive to query `Server1`

and

> it would be nice if each server had a local link to that directory as
>   if the directory was stored locally

are contradictory.  The former implies that you think a network mount would not be feasible in your environment.  The latter implies that you want the only set of data on `Server1` and that don't want to rsync seperate copies between locations.

[This is a nice article on NFS](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/index.html), how it works, how to set it up, and its security.  I think you'll find that a network share via NFS will be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have local copies, `rsync` the directories from server1 to the other ones. But you need to have a concept how to deploy changes made on server2 to server1. on the other hand, do you rellay **know** (e.g., you benchmarked it) that your nfs access would be slow or dou you **feel** (there is sth in your stomach) it'll be slow?

However rsync example four you:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

How huge is huge?

The traditional way to do this is put /opt/fizz/buzz into Server1's /etc/exports file and restart NFS to export it, then "mount Server1:/opt/fizz/buzz /buzz" on server2.